# Selecting lines in a file based on two column values using Perl

Tags: perl

In my dataset there are 2 columns, the first is a "reference" column, the second a "value" column. The reference values may be repeated several times, however each will have a different value associated with them.

e.g.

```
ref1  0.0234
ref1  2.8951
ref1  1.4565
ref2  20.346
ref2  24.345
```

I need to make a script which will take the line containing the highest value for each reference ID and place it in a new file. For my example, the new file would look like:

```
ref1  2.8951
ref2  24.345
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk for this task:

```
$ awk '$2+0>a[$1]{a[$1]=$2;b[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) {print b[i]}}' infile                           
ref1 2.8951
ref2 24.345
```

Perl is incredible useful but for this simple tasks in my opinion you can't beat awk simplicity.

Here’s the internals, when second column is greater than previous value stored for that reference ($1), we keep/update two structures (hash):

- a : greater value and ref
- b : line ref.

In the END part we take care of showing the results , so we link the max reference with its line.

Comment: Such a terse solution, especially in response to a Perl question, requires some amount of explanation.

Comment: That's true, this does handle multiple fields! +1 for extensibility

Comment: Thanks so much! Wasn't sure if awk could handle this, but I'm clearly wrong.I didn't realise this would be an issue (my bad), but this command doesn't seem to also print lines where a "reference" only appears once, or where a set of references all have a "0" value

Comment: A perl taliban , i'm sure xP

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$ perl -anle '
    $h{$F[0]} = $F[1] > $h{$F[0]} 
              ? $F[1]
              : $h{$F[0]}
              ;
    END {print "$_ $h{$_}" for sort keys %h}
' file
ref1 2.8951
ref2 24.345
```

**Explanation**

- While reading file, we create a hash `%h`:

  - Key is the reference id
  - Value is coressponding value
- If current id has value greater than value of id in hash `%h`, we update value to hash, otherwise keep current value.
- After finish reading file, we print keys, values pair in `%h`, sort by key order.

Answer (score 1):

klashxx's solution is close, but the extra array really isn't necessary.

```
awk '$2+0 > a[$1] {
         a[$1] = $2
     }
     END {
         for (i in a) {
             print i, a[i]
         }
     }' ref
```

In my opinion, `awk` is the "proper" tool for this job because it's built to handle data in records like this. While I recommend you read up on `awk` to get the full gist of this program, here's an explanation for the lines to give some idea of what's going on.

`awk` runs through all the lines in your file and operates on them. The first block in curly braces contains actions only to be taken on lines where the second field ($2) is greater than the value of the saved value in your array for that reference value. The +0 forces a conversion to a numeric value. Inside this block, the $2 value is then assigned to array a, with an index of your reference value.

The END block gets called only after all lines in your file have been read, once. It loops through the array you have, and prints the indices and values from the array.

Comment: Yep, you're right ,but i choose that solution for handle multiple fields. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
perl -alne '
     unless (defined($h{$F[0]})){ 
        $h{$F[0]}=0
     } 
     if($h{$F[0]} <= $F[1] ){
         $h{$F[0]}=$F[1]
     }END{
         foreach( keys %h){print "$_ $h{$_}"}
     }' file

ref1 2.8951
ref2 24.345
```

All in one line:

```
perl -alne 'unless (defined($h{$F[0]})){ $h{$F[0]}=0}; if($h{$F[0]} <= $F[1] ){$h{$F[0]}=$F[1];}END{foreach( keys %h){print "$_ $h{$_}"}}' file
ref1 2.8951
ref2 24.345
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's been answered, I'm going to be anal and follow the instructions to the letter and make an actual perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

unless ($ARGV[0]) { die "Missing source file as first arguement\n" }
unless ($ARGV[1]) { die "Missing destination file as second arguement\n" }

unless (-e $ARGV[0]) { die "Filename $ARGV[0] not found\n" }
if (-e $ARGV[1]) { die "Cowardly refusing to overwrite $ARGV[1]\n" }

open OLD,"<$ARGV[0]" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
my %refs;
while (<OLD>)
{
        my ($ref, $value) = split(/\s+/,$_);
        if ($refs{$ref})
        {
                if ($value > $refs{$ref}) { $refs{$ref} = $value }
        } else { $refs{$ref} = $value }
}

open NEW,">>$ARGV[1]";
foreach my $ref (keys(%refs))
{
        print "$ref\t$refs{$ref}\n";
        print NEW "$ref\t$refs{$ref}\n";
}
```

- `%refs` is keeps track of the highest value for each ref, as the `while`-loop traverses the file.
- For each line, it checks the value against the one stored in `%refs` and updates if higher.
- At the end, it prints the data to the new file, as well as prints the result.

Not as clean and compact as some of the other suggestions, but should be easily readable and editable to someone not adept at perl.